# Strange behaviour when comparing cast float to zero

Tags: c++, floating-point, comparison

I'm currently trying to learn about floating point representation in depth, so I played around a bit. While doing so, I stumbled on some strange behaviour; I can't really work out what's happening, and I'd be very grateful for some insight. Apologies if this has been answered, I found it quite hard to google!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  float minVal = pow(2,-149); // set to smallest float possible
  
  float nextCheck = static_cast<float>(minVal/2.0f); // divide by two
  bool isZero = (static_cast<float>(minVal/2.0f) == 0.0f); // this evaluates to false
  bool isZero2 = (nextCheck == 0.0f); // this evaluates to true
  cout << nextCheck << " " << isZero << " " << isZero2 << endl;
  // this outputs 0 0 1
  
  return 0;

}
```

Essentially what's happening is:

- I set minVal to be the smallest float that can be represented using
  single precision
- Dividing by 2 should yield 0 -- we're at the minimum
- Indeed, isZero2 does return true, but isZero returns false.

What's going on -- I would have thought them to be identical? Is the compiler trying to be clever, saying that dividing any number cannot possibly yield zero?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you sure that `pow(2,-149)` returns the smallest possible float? There are lots of calculation imprecision issues.

Comment: It seems to work. The binary representation returns 1, which is indeed the smallest possible float: 
Sign = 0; Exponent = 0; Mantissa = 1, so:
2^(-23) * 2^(-126) = 2 ^(-149)

Comment: I get your expected output on g++ 4.8.2. `0 1 1`.

Comment: and for me too. It's `0 1 1`. What is your OS and compiler? Maybe VS?

Comment: Isn't a C++ implementation allowed to use a wide exponent range? That is, it can act like Java without `strictfp`.

Comment: I also got it working...

Comment: Check [`std::numeric_limits::epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)

Comment: `ldexp` is a much more reliable way of getting a specific float value than `pow`.

Comment: Well, this is bizarre. I compile it under Windows using Cygwin and g++ (GCC) 4.8.2, and I get 0 0 1, as I wrote. I compile it under Ubuntu using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2 and I get 0 1 1. Can there be any difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `isZero` and `isZero2` can evaluate to different values, and `isZero` can be false, is that the C++ compiler is allowed to implement intermediate floating-point operations with more precision than the type of the expression would indicate, but the extra precision has to be dropped on assignment.

Typically, when generating code for the 387 historical FPU, the generated instructions work on either the 80-bit extended-precision type, or, if the FPU is set to a 53-bit significand (e.g. on Windows), a strange floating-point type with 53-bit significands and 15-bit exponents.

Either way, `minVal/2.0f` is evaluated exactly because the exponent range allows to represent it, but assigning it to `nextCheck` rounds it to zero.

If you are using GCC, there is the additional problem that `-fexcess-precision=standard` has not yet been implemented for the C++ front-end, meaning that the code generated by g++ does not implement exactly what the standard recommends.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel like I almost understand now. Just to clarify: in my windows compiler (GCC), -fexcess-precision=standard has not been implemented, so even though I am casting as a float, it may be using its weird internal 53 bit representation. On g++ in Ubuntu on the other hand it does the cast and then treats it as a float in the expected way. Is that right?

Comment: @noctilux More likely is that on Ubuntu, it is using the SSE2 floating-point instructions, and generates a single-precision division for `minVal/2.0f`, which produces the expected result at the expected precision. You can resolve the question by using the `-S` option to GCC so that it generates the assembly code in readable form. Instructions that start with `f` are historical 387 instructions. `divss` is the instruction you'll see on the other hand if the compiler generates SSE2 code.

Comment: Pascal, you are absolutely right. Thank you for the very insightful answers!

Comment: One last question: does this mean that on my Windows machine, all floating point variables are in fact stored in the 387 representation on the hardware level, and float and double are just  abstractions maintained by the compiler?

Comment: @noctilus When the standard is followed, the compiler can claim to follow IEEE 754 as long as the extra precision only applies to intermediate results, and variables contain 32 or 64 bits of floating-point values in IEEE 754 format.